# How can keep format when spoiler sections are opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a project lately which uses js, css and HTML. I have a problem in which when the spoiler buttons expand, the other buttons lose their position, how would i fix this?

(Problem) https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp5u6.jpg

html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Tricks & Flips Progression </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\zhewi2\Desktop\website\stylesheet.css"></link>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="C:\Users\zhewi2\Desktop\website\style.js"></script>

    </head>

<h2 id=learn>What I want to learn (progress to sand)</h2>

    <div class="learn">
    <input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler1(this);" value="Front flip variaion (ramp)" />
    <div1 class="inner" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>Front full</li>
            <li>Double Front</li>
            <li>Aerial Twist</li>
        </ul>
    </div1>

    <div class="learn">
    <input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler2(this);" value="Front flip variaion (flat)" />
    <div2 class="inner" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>front 180</li>
            <li>Webster</li>
            <li>Loser</li>
        </ul>
    </div2>

    <div class="learn" id="learn1">
    <input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler3(this);" value="Backflip variations" />
    <div3 class="inner" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>Off-axis backtuck</li>
            <li>Back Full</li>
        </ul>
    </div3>

    <div class="learn" id="learn2">
    <input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler4(this);" value="Sideflip Variations (ramp)" />
    <div4 class="inner" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>Tunnel flip</li>
        </ul>
    </div4>

    <div class="learn">
    <input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler5(this);" value="Twists and other tricks" />
    <div5 class="inner" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>B-Twist</li>
            <li>Grandmaster Swipe</li>
        </ul>
    </div5>


<h2 id=progress>What I can do into sand (progress to flat)</h2>
    <div class="learning">
    <input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler6(this);" value="Backflip variations" />
    <div6 class="inner" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>Layout</li>
            <li>Swing Gainer</li>
            <li> standing ST backflip</li>
        </ul>
    </div6>

    <div class="learning">
    <input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler7(this);" value="Frontlip variations (ramp)" />
    <div7 class="inner" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>Iron man</li>
            <li>Webster</li>
            <li>Front Layout</li>
        </ul>
    </div7>

<h2 id=learnt> What I can do flat (grass and above)</h2>

    <div class="learnt">
    <input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler8(this);" value="Backflip variations" />
    <div8 class="inner" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li>Backtuck</li>
        </ul>
    </div8>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
#learn {
    color:red;
}
#progress {
    color:orange;
}
#learnt {
    color:green;
}
div1 {
    color:blue;
}
div2 {
    color:blue;
    position:relative;
    left: 150px;
}
div3 {
    color:blue;
    position:relative;
    left: 300px;
}
div4 {
    color:blue;
    position:relative;
    left: 450px;
}
div5 {
    color:blue;
    position:relative;
    left: 600px;
}
div6 {
    color:blue;
}
div7 {
    color:blue;
    position:relative;
    left: 120px;
}
div8 {
    color:blue;
}

.learn {
    display:inline;
}
.learning {
    display:inline;
}
.learnt {
    display inline;
}
```

JS code:

```
function showSpoiler1(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div1")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }

function showSpoiler2(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div2")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }

function showSpoiler3(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div3")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }

function showSpoiler4(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div4")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }

function showSpoiler5(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div5")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }

function showSpoiler6(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div6")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }

function showSpoiler7(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div7")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }

function showSpoiler8(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div8")[0];
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }
```

How can I keep the spoiler buttons in a line while their content expands below them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it a fair bit more dynamic, but it will make it more complicated, so I'll stick to the basics.

You could just put all the buttons together, and then have the spoiler sections:

```
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler1(this);" value="Front flip variaion (ramp)" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler2(this);" value="Front flip variaion (flat)" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler3(this);" value="Backflip variations" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler4(this);" value="Sideflip Variations (ramp)" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler5(this);" value="Twists and other tricks" />

<div id="div1" class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>Front full</li>
        <li>Double Front</li>
        <li>Aerial Twist</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>front 180</li>
        <li>Webster</li>
        <li>Loser</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="div3" class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>Off-axis backtuck</li>
        <li>Back Full</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="div4" class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>Tunnel flip</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="div5" class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li>B-Twist</li>
        <li>Grandmaster Swipe</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As it is the sections in between opening which is creating the gaps.

Note, I have removed your `<div class="learn">` tags as they had no closing tags so it was invalid html. I also added ids to each `<div>` and removed the numbered naming of the tags as, for example, `<div1>` is not a standard tag. Therefore your js would change to be like this:

```
function showSpoiler1(obj)
{
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementById("div1");
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
        inner.style.display = "";
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
}
```

---

An alternative to moving the buttons, you could use CSS to place them at the top. You would need to wrap the section in a `<div>` and set it to `position:relative;`. You could then set the buttons to `position:absolute;` and define distance from top and left of the div wrapper to set their positions at the top. However, this would require knowing their width (which could change with font size) and would be messier than I think it needs to be.